# What is the 'else' of a one line if statement correspondece?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement, procedural-programming

In javascript I get confused with the nested if's elses

when a JS compiler/engine has this code to interpret

```
if (cond1)
if (cond2)
statement1
else
statement2
```

(It is not indented on purpose)

Does it gets interpreted like this?

```
if (cond1) {
  if (cond2) {
    statement1
  }
}
else {
  statement2
}
```

Or like this?

```
if (cond1) {
  if (cond2) {
    statement1
  }
  else {
    statement2
  }
}
```

The question would be: Do the 'else' corresponds to the first or second 'if'?

I would like to know also if this problem of interpretation has some name (like 'operator precedence') (I'm sure it has). I can't find this issue in internet, because I don't know how to search for it by its name.

It might be a little obvious, but I'm going to say it: I ask about javascript because I'm using it right now, but this question could be about almost any procedural language.

Comment: My suggestion would be to write it out and `alert(line_number)` just to validate, but I believe it would be the second if statement

Comment: This is a text book example of why one should ALWAYS use the braces.  There is never any ambiguity when the braces are supplied AND never any opportunity for someone maintaining your code to accidentally mess it up with a simple edit because they don't realize what you were intending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be the second one in JS. It would throw an error in python and get your nose punched in php as soon as a colleague debugs your code.

Comment: Only in PHP? I'd like to think every language would prefer people not confuse others this much.

Comment: True, but you don't know my colleagues.